# conversion of string containing times to 24-hour times I can do math with - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, time, substring

I am trying to find a way in jQuery/javascript to reliably convert strings like these: 
"10:30 am – 11:00 pm" or this "6:45 am – 9:50 pm"
into two pieces each, 1030 and 2300 or 645 and 2150 respectively. The end goal is to see if the current time is in between the two, I think I have that part down, but the conversion to 24-hour time is throwing me off.
Here is a (non)working example but it might help to better illustrate my idea: http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/LkxBb
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to define every minute of every hour in 24 hour format?

Comment: Would you be open to using a date utility library like http://momentjs.com/? Would simplify things quite a bit: `moment("10:45 pm", "hh:mm A").format("HHmm")` would output `2245` ... or you could use the `isBefore/isAfter` tests from moment.js directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this with some regex magic:

```
var str = '6:45 am – 9:50 pm';

var result = [],
    regex = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s?(am|pm)/gi;

str.replace(regex, function(_, hours, minutes, meridian) {
  hours =+ hours;
  if (meridian.toLowerCase() == 'pm') hours += 12;
  result.push( +(hours +''+ minutes));
});

console.log(result); //=> [645, 2150]
```

Comment: =+ is a valid javascript operator?

Comment: @mikeyUX: Not an operator. It's same as `hours = +hours` which just casts `hours` to a number, since the regex matches a string.

Comment: i see... short (though perhaps less clear) way of doing parseInt(hours);  Cool - thanks for the insight :)

Comment: Yeah, it's the same as in `push`, you could write it like `parseInt(String(hours) + String(minutes))` but it really seems more convoluted once you know the rules of the _super overloaded_ `+` operator.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter <- please correct me if I'm wrong: the underscore is the required match argument (unnecessary in this case) and the hours/minutes/meridium are the p1/p2/p3 - refering to the sub expressions defined by the parentheses within the regex?

Comment: You got it. `replace` is just used to loop in this case. It's more readable than the `exec` and `while` loop alternative.

Comment: This worked great, I really appreciate it, now I just need to learn this magic - regex seems really powerful while looking incoherent at first glance.  Thank you to everyone who offered their solutions or input!

Answer (score 1):

In the following code the input string is not validated for the correct format, it assumes the string is always in the correct format

```
function time24h(parts){
    var elms = /^(\d+):(\d+)$/.exec(parts[0]);
    return +elms[1] + (/^am$/i.test(parts[1]) ? 0 : 12) + elms[2];
}

function converter(string){
    var array = [];
    var regex = /^(\d+:\d+)\s+(am|pm)\s+.\s+(\d+:\d+)\s+(am|pm)$/;
    var parts = regex.exec(string);
    array.push(time24h([parts[1], parts[2]]));
    array.push(time24h([parts[3], parts[4]]));
    return array;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qj6HY/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
  /**
   * Returns time numeric value
   * @param timeIn12hours
   * @return {*}
   */
  function get24hoursTime(timeIn12hours)
  {
    timeIn12hours = timeIn12hours.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    var timeParts = timeIn12hours.split(" ");
    var timePeriod = timeParts[1];
    var hourParts = timeParts[0].split(":");

    if(timePeriod == 'pm')
      return (12 + parseInt(hourParts[0])) + hourParts[1];

    return hourParts[0] + hourParts[1];
  }

  /**
   * Returns object with period numeric values
   * @param periodIn12hours
   * @return {Object}
   */
  function get24hoursPeriod(periodIn12hours)
  {
    var parts = periodIn12hours.split("-");

    return {
      'from': get24hoursTime(parts[0]),
      'to': get24hoursTime(parts[1])
    }
  }

  val = get24hoursPeriod("6:45 am - 9:50 pm");

  alert("From: " + val.from + ", to: "+ val.to);
```